# python fabric mysql privileges

Tags: python, string-formatting

Trying to set mysql user privileges with fabric.

```
run("mysql -u %s -p%s -e 'grant all on %s.* to '%s'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD'" % (user, dbpasswd, account))
```

Error

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

```
run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "grant all on %s.* to '%s\'@\'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD'"' % (user, dbpasswd, account, account))

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your tuple to `(user, dbpasswd, account, user)` and you should be good. This error happens because you have 4 replacements tokens (%s) but only have 3 items in your tuple.

Comment: run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "grant all on %s.* to '%s'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD'"' % (user, dbpasswd, account, account))
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


same command runs without any issue on cli

mysql -u root -ppassword -e "grant all on xentoxoxxxc.* to 'xentoxoxxxc'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD';"