# mysql user privileges with fabric python regex

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python fabric mysql privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392721/python-fabric-mysql-privileges)

Trying to set mysql user privileges with fabric.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

```
run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "grant all on %s.* to '%s\'@\'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD'"' % (user, dbpasswd, account, account))

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting stackoverflow did for you and you'll see where your string ends by the change in colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your line to:

```
run('mysql -u %s -p%s -e "grant all on %s.* to \'%s\'@\'localhost\' identified by \'PASSWORD\'"' % (user, dbpasswd, account, account))
```